# NetSuite - INVALID_CSTM_FIELD_REF

Tags: php, netsuite

I added a custom field to Purchase Order and added a value for the field. Now when I search the same Purchase Order from the web service call I get the following error.

```
INVALID_CSTM_FIELD_REF
```

Please guide me how to resolve this. There are no help in google.

Thanks in advance...!!!

EDIT:
I added a custom field called "PO Rep Id" (text) to PO object. Then I went to a existing PO detail page -> Edit the PO and add "B18" as the value of my custom field. Now I can see the value from the NetSuite interface (sandbox).

Now I try to get the same PO from web service call using 2014 PHP development toolkit by using the internalId.

Not is gived me this error. INVALID_CSTM_FIELD_REF.

When I remove the value "B18" from the NetSuite interface, I get the PO result from the PHP call.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please edit to explain exactly what you did to get that error? Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited.

Comment: Can you post your PHP code that is sending a request to NS web service?

Comment: $gr = new GetRequest();
$gr->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$gr->baseRef->internalId = <poNumber>;
$gr->baseRef->type = "purchaseOrder";

This is the only thing I do. When I have value to "PO Rep ID" it gives me the error. When I empty that value from NetSuite interface, I can see the data set from here.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. NetSuite gives me this error when only search it with the internalId. When I use a "searchBasic" class and do the search it returns me the result.